# datagridview layout behaviour

Tags: layout, datagridview, docking

I have c#/2008/winform application.
I have a form with a picture banner, and a datagridview below it

I want the picture banner to remain fixed in size, and the datagridview to rezise
and fill the rest of the form.

I have set the picturebox to dock=top 
(Also pos=0,0, sizemode=centerimage - but these setting are not the problem)

My datagridview misbehaves no matter what i do
If i do dock=fill, it starts from the top of form, and is obstructed by the picture
If i try to set dock=bottom it does not resize with the container

I am aware of the concept of layoutmanagers but this is just a quick app
so i hope i dont need one here.

Any ideas ?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better workaround but the first thing I found that worked was to introduce a panel control.

Make you picture box Dock=Top, then place the panel below it with Dock=Fill, then your DataGridView goes inside the panel with Dock = Fill.

Comment: And as an aside - I can't actually replicate the behaviour your state where the DGV with Dock=Fill goes to the top of the form - it docks under the picture box when I try this.